# Flutter: Combining ScrollView and PageView Widgets

Tags: flutter

```
 body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(height: 600, color: Colors.red),
              Container( // <------ Container A
                child: PageView(
                  controller: _activityPanelController,
                  children: [
                    Container(height: 300, color: Colors.white),
                    Container(height: 300, color: Colors.blue),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

I want to set the Container A's height to its child to use the `PageView` widget inside the `SingleChildScrollView` in this case.

How can I achieve to put the `PageView` widget inside the `SingleChildScrollView` widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't make `PageView` as high as it's children. You'd do so with `IntrinsicHeight` widget and by removing `SizedBox`, but you'll get the following error:

```
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderViewport does not support returning intrinsic dimensions.
```

Also, you can't get rid of the `SizedBox`, because of the `ListView` (the same happens with `Column` and `SingleChildScrollView`), it's children get unbounded height, and `PageView` tries to get as big as possible. After removing `SizedBox`, you'll see this:

```
The following assertion was thrown during performResize():
Horizontal viewport was given unbounded height.
```

Working example:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final boxHeight = 600.0;

  return ListView(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(height: boxHeight, color: Colors.red),
      Container(height: boxHeight, color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent),
      SizedBox(
        height: boxHeight,
        child: PageView(
          controller: PageController(),
          children: [
             // ...
          ].map((e) => SingleChildScrollView(child: e)).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

https://www.dartpad.dev/619458e188ce97f9cd1272441b7a3bf3?null_safety=true